# Is it possible to display the results of applying a Haskell type family function?

Tags: haskell, ghci, type-families

For example, if I have these weird types:

```Haskell
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
type family WeirdFamily a
type instance WeirdFamily () = Int
type instance WeirdFamily (a, b) = (a, WeirdFamily b)
```

Can I display (e.g. in GHCi) the result of `WeirdFamily (Bool, (Char, ()))` by typing something like:

```Haskell
:t WeirdFamily (Bool, (Char, ()))
```

into GHCi?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `kind!`.

```
:kind! WeirdFamily (Bool, (Char, ()))
WeirdFamily (Bool, (Char, ())) :: *
= (Bool, (Char, Int))
```

Comment: Perfect! Looking at the help for `kind!` it says "also print the normalised type" - is there some documentation for what a "normalised type" is somewhere?

Comment: @David "normalized" here stands for "simplified using equations (applied left-to-right) as much as possible".

Comment: This is great, but how do I normalize a parameterized type? For example `StM (ExceptT e m) a` (which should normalize to `StM m (Either e a)`.

Answer (score 1):

So I have figured out an answer. Type this into GHCi:

```Haskell
f :: WeirdFamily (Bool, (Char, ())); f = undefined
:t f
```

gives `f :: (Bool, (Char, Int))`

But it feels like there should be a "cleaner" way. Is there?