# Is it possible to normalize a type that contains free type variables in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-level-computation

My goal is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979361/is-it-possible-to-display-the-results-of-applying-a-haskell-type-family-function): I would like to normalize a type in GHCi. But the type contains free type variables. For example, the type

```
StM (ExceptT e m) a
```

should normalize to

```
StM m (Either e a)
```

But when I typed `!k StM (ExceptT e m) a` into GHCi, it complained about those free type variables. Are there any other ways of doing so in Haskell?

Comment: You can't use type variables, but you could define your own custom concrete types `data M a`, `data E`, `data A` and use those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> import Control.Monad.Except
> :set -XTypeFamilies -XUndecidableInstances
> type family StM f a where StM (ExceptT e m) a = StM m (Either e a)
```

You can use partial types `_`, it's unfortunate it gets printed as `GHC.Types.Any`:

```
> :set -XPartialTypeSignatures -Wno-partial-type-signatures
> :kind! StM (ExceptT _ _) _
StM (ExceptT _ _) _ :: *
= StM Any (Either Any Any)
```

but it also works if you find concrete types

```
> :kind! StM (ExceptT String []) Int
StM (ExceptT String []) Int :: *
= StM [] (Either [Char] Int)
```

or you can quantify explicitly

```
> :set -XRankNTypes
> :kind! forall m e a. StM (ExceptT e m) a
forall m e a. StM (ExceptT e m) a :: *
= StM m (Either e a)
```

I think it would be a good feature to implicitly quantify for `:kind` so you can write `:kind StM (ExceptT e m) a` and it inserts the foralls for you.